# How to play audio in Jupyter notebook with VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, audio, jupyter-notebook

Using a jupyter notebook in VSCode, I'm trying to run the following code from this [documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html):

```
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import Audio
framerate = 44100
t = np.linspace(0,5,framerate*5)
data = np.sin(2*np.pi*220*t) + np.sin(2*np.pi*224*t)
Audio(data, rate=framerate)
```

However, I only get this

[image]

If I press play button, then nothing happens...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of today, it seems VSCode Jupyter extension does not support audio. You can track the issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1012) on their Github.

One solution can be merging [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-notebook-renderers/pull/33) pull request and rebuilding VSCode, which is not suggested.

The preferred alternate solution is using `jupyter lab` instead of VSCode for such use cases.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 1.7, it seems [they’ve fixed it](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1012#issuecomment-1237298236).

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this working a few months ago.

But currently my system is Ubuntu 23.04 with miniconda including python 3.11 and Visual Studio Code via snap, so latest version.
I can press the play button, but can not hear any sound.
With Jupyter Lab in miniconda, with the same conda kernel, sound is working fine.

So it seems that Audio via IPython is broken in VSCode while it worked a few months ago.

[EDIT 2023/05/20] I uninstalled the snap version of VSCode. And installed it directly:

```
sudo apt install ./code_1.78.2-1683731010_amd64.deb
```

and after that it all works fine. So my issue was snap specific.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024-02-14 this works

```
from IPython.display import Audio

Audio(filename=wav_filename, autoplay=True)
```

[image]

But there is [an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/178642) that seems difficult to be solved. VScode ignores the `autoplay=True`.

But if you click Play it works fine.

---

I just had to workaround that with

```
import os
os.system("play --vol 0.05 /path/to/file.wav")
```

I needed the Autoplay because I have sounds for errors and for end-of-notebook-reached and those must be played automatically to tell me stuff with sounds (among other sounds).